# Automatically allocating memory for a C struct

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I have been using C/C++ on and off but today I saw in a certain book something I had never seen before:

```
struct item {
   int code;
   float prize;
};

void main() {

   struct item a,*b;

   a.code = 123;
   a.prize = 150.75;
   printf ("Code: %d, Prize %d", a.code, a.prize);

   b->code = 124;
   b->prize = 200.75;

   printf ("Code: %d, Prize %d", a->code, a->prize);
}
```

The above prints the values as normal which was a surprise regarding the `*b` part. Since b is a pointer, the memory allocated for it should be on the stack with the size of `size_t` (ex. 64 bits) while its data should be available only by allocating it separately on the heap:

```
b = (item*)malloc(sizeof(struct item));
```

Apparently though, **there is no need for that**. How is this possible?

Comment: It is undefined behavior. It's seemingly working for one case and might crash with the slightest change of the code, or another run.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking about the behavior of undefined behavior is futile.

Comment: There was a typo/error in the book, as it is UB currently.

Comment: `a->code, a->prize);` should be `b->code, b->prize);`, right?

Comment: why do we have to have 500 questions a week about "why didnt my program crash when i wrote to uninitialized pointer / out of bounds of array"

Comment: Please name the book and author

Comment: FYI, there's nothing called `C/C++`, it's UB. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly diagnosed, `b` is an uninitialized pointer.  Accessing members for reading and writing invokes undefined behavior, no memory is *automatically* allocated for uninitialized pointers to point to. Uninitialized pointer just have an indeterminate value that should not be used.

In your case, the program seems to behave *normally*, but it is just a coincidence, and an unlikely one on modern systems: if `b` happens to have a value that points to some accessible memory, so no segmentation fault occurs, but who knows what object was modified and what further consequences this may have...

Don't do this, and compile with more warnings enabled as current compilers are able to detect such errors: `gcc -Wall -Wextra` or `clang -Weverything`.

There are several other problems in your code:

- You do not include the standard header `<stdio.h>` ;
- you pass a `float` for `printf` format `%d` ;
- you define `main` as returning `void`, it should return `int` ;
- you do not end your output to `stdout` with a newline.

The second item also invokes undefined behavior.  The other 3 usually do not have dire consequences, but should still be corrected.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct item {
   int code;
   float prize;
};

int main(void) {
    struct item a, *b;

    a.code = 123;
    a.prize = 150.75;
    printf("Code: %d, Prize %f\n", a.code, a.prize);

    b = malloc(sizeof(*b));
    if (b != NULL) {
        b->code = 124;
        b->prize = 200.75;
        printf ("Code: %d, Prize %f\n", b->code, b->prize);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Leaving out `#include <stdio.h>` does not - in itself - make this code have undefined behaviour.   The 1989/90 C standard stipulates that, if an undeclared function is called, it is assumed to return `int` and may have an arbitrary number of arguments.   The only way that results in undefined behaviour is if the compiler assumes something different from the actual function.  More recent C standards, and all C++ standards, require the code to be rejected  (although some C compilers and some older [pre-standard] C++ compilers do not do this).

Comment: @Peter: You have a valid point. we had a language lawyer discussion about this topic and it is a moot point arguing on the precise consequences in real life and as per the different versions of the C Standards, I amended the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

In your case, `b->code` and `b->prize` are accessing uninitialized memory and the result is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). ***Don't do that***.

To elaborate, there is no <del>*magical*</del> automatic memory allocation happening to make those pointers point to any valid memory. Just because C *allows* you to write a code which access uninitialized pointer does not mandate it is a *valid* code. You **must** make the pointers to point to some valid memory location, before you can access (read from or write to) them.

Any decent compiler is likely (*though not required to*) to produce a warning against code like that. For `gcc`, enabling `-Wuninitialized` (enabled by adding `-Wall`) should show a warning like

> *warning: ‘b’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]*

That said, you have **another major problem**. You are passing a `float` as `%d` format specifier argument, which again, invokes UB on it's own.

```
 printf ("Code: %d, Prize %d", a.code, a.prize);
                         ^^^           ^^^^^^^^
```

Related, quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1

> [...] If any argument is
>   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.

You should be using `%f` to print a `float`.

Finally, for a hosted environment, the signature of `main()` should be `int main(void)`, at least, to conform to the standard.